# is margin the same thing of texture bleeding?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I want to know if margin size , is a space further the UV coordinates space? Ok , but if I put "margin = 0.006 " for example, it means that there are 0.006 pixels further to sort texture bleeding? or just a simple space to separate island?

Comment: See here in the [Blender Manual information about UV margins](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html?highlight=margin). They are basically the distance between UV islands

Comment: ahh ok! I think it has two functionalities , ok thanks